# Translate SkyDrive links to OneDrive

Tags: onedrive, hyperlink, links

I was reading a blog that was written back when Microsoft's cloud storage was called SkyDrive. And I saw a link containing some sample source code, this is the link -

https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=1e3f9e1e2f8bc994&resid=1E3F9E1E2F8BC994!2323&parid=1E3F9E1E2F8BC994!181

Clicking on this link redirects to OneDrive, but it says that the item was not found. Can someone please confirm my assumption that the reason the link doesn't work is because it's deleted (and not because it's a SkyDrive link which is incompatible with OneDrive) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That assumption would be correct, the error being: `This item might have been deleted, expired, or you might not have permission to view it. Contact the owner of this item for more information.` Meaning that either the file was deleted, the file link expired or the owner stopped sharing it.